Using MMD for Feature Selection with Linear Regression: Valid Approach?
I'm using Maximum Mean Discrepancy (MMD) for feature selection (i.e., to select the features that minimize the dissimilarity between the training and testing datasets). I'm aware that MMD introduces non-linearity through kernels. However, I plan to apply linear regression, specifically using GLM Possion, using the features selected by MMD.
I have some reservations about the validity of this approach, as it seems contradictory to use non-linear methods for feature selection and then apply linear regression. I'd appreciate some expert insights and suggestions, alternatively, what could other techniques be used instead of the MMD?
